# What are the boundary conditions for Navier's Equations of motion in seismic?

Tags: geophysics, waves, seismic, mathematics

Navier's equations of motion in seismic have 3 solutions, according to how it is resolved (boundary conditions):

- for V<sub>p</sub> (compression waves)
- for V<sub>s</sub> (shear waves)
- for V<sub>r</sub> (Rayleigh waves)

I know the boundary conditions for V<sub>r</sub>, that is the half-space (null stress at the surface and null displacements and stress at infinite depth).

What would be the boundary conditions for V<sub>p</sub> and V<sub>s</sub> solutions and why do they derivate for infinite medium and not half-space? What does an infinite medium imply?

Comment: Could you update your question with the equation you're referring to? It's not clear if you just mean the elastic wave equation or not; I'm not used to finding this from the Navier(-Stokes?) equations. Even then, it isn't entirely clear to me what you're asking for. The compressional and shear waves are body waves, they need a "body" to propagate through -- not a surface with which they'll interact (which will transform them into, e.g., Rayleigh waves). So a typical assumption is vanishing stress and displacement at infinity; look up the "Sommerfeld radiation condition" maybe?

Comment: I support what @Erik is presenting and asking about. 

I'll supplement the content currently here with just referencing to some classic books that I believe and hope can certainly answer your question(s). Here are two that do an outstanding job of literally deriving various elastic wave equations for half-spaces and other  more realistic scenarios: 1] Petroleum Seismology (2005) and 2] Seismic Data Analysis.

Also - and I know this is quite hard sometimes - try to isolate one "thing" you aren't sure of and figure that out. Then, move onto other topics.